# how to set valuetype as positive int?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, value-type, typeof

Question should be self explanatory. I have a datagridview which has a column whose cells should accept only positive integer upon user input.

So how can I set something like this:

```
            dgv.Columns[i].ValueType = typeof(int > 0);
```

??

Of course I can handle a separate validation at `cellValueChanged` event. But since I have all validation handled in `DataError` event automatically (since I set valueType for each column), I would like my above validation to be handled here

```
    private void dgv_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        // not fair..
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

How to?

Update: Since I hear a lot of negatives about `uint` (as proposed by one of the answers) like uints are not CLS compliant, not all language supports it etc, is it ok to use just for validation purpose like above?

Comment: `dgv.Columns[i].ValueType`...?

Comment: CLS compliance only matters on public classes, the kind that code written in another language could use.  Clearly that doesn't apply to a private control.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh thanks. I only use for internal validation, just to set as valueType..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upper part of the question should be easily solved like this:

```
dgv.Columns[i].ValueType = typeof(uint);
```

The lower part I don't understand at all.

Comment: its ok that you didn't understand, not vital to the question. But I hear a lot of negatives about uint. Is it ok to use just for validation purposes?

Comment: Be careful that uint is not int>0, uint is non-negative (includes 0)

Answer (score 6):

Declare uint type variable

minimum of uint is 0

maximun od uint is 4294967295

Comment: The one thing to be concerned about is if you're worried about overflow or underflow:  if you subtract 1 from a uint of value 0, you'll get 4294967294 as your result.